# Why does Google Cache break my iframes?

Tags: google-search, googlebot, iframe, cross-origin

In HTML5, `iframe` comes as a replacement for `frameset`.

However, when I load my iframe-based page in SeaMonkey through Google Cache, the page appears empty, other than the standard Google Cache header and some minor non-iframe insignia.

Digging around makes me believe it's due to this header added up by Google for my cached page:

> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Which makes no sense, because then the whole cached page is empty!  Is this expected?  Is there a workaround to make Google not break the "Cached" link?  Why is there a need for this header, isn't `webcache.googleusercontent.com` already explicitly dedicated to, well, user content?!

Answer (score 2):

> In HTML5, iframe comes as a replacement for frameset.

iframe has been around since HTML 4. It was introduced at the same time as frameset. There isn't a replacement for frameset since framesets are just awful.

> Is this expected?

Yes. If the server says that only pages from the same origin may frame a page, then it will appear blank if framed from a different origin. Browsers display an error message in the console.

> Is there a workaround to make Google not break the "Cached" link?

Don't stick it in a frame, or cache it yourself.

> Why is there a need for this header

To defend against phishing and other unsavoury attempts to pass off other people's content as one's own.

(NB: If you do cache it yourself, then be careful you aren't opening yourself up to a copyright claim).

> isn't webcache.googleusercontent.com already explicitly dedicated to, well, user content?

No. It's content scraped from third party sites all over the WWW.